# Map over HashMap and avoid empty results

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming, hashmap

I have an immutable `HashMap`:

```
val hashmap = Seq(1,2,3,3,2).groupBy(identity).map({x => x._1 -> x._2.length})

println(hashmap)
// HashMap(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 2)
```

I try to filter it by value (2) and get the keys:

```
val res = hashmap.map({ case (key, value) => if (value == 2) key})

println(res)
// List((), 2, 3)
```

However, it returns an empty tuple if there is a key/value pair in `hashmap` which does not satisfy `value==2`.

Where do these empty tuples come from? Is there an **easy** approach how to avoid them?

I want to have a `List(2, 3)` as a result.

[Online code](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/np71GZiYRMiP8psTr3bZGQ)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Omitting `else` clause

```
if (value == 2) key
```

is equivalent to

```
if (value == 2) key else ()
```

which is why

```
hashmap.map({ case (key, value) => if (value == 2) key})
```

evaluates to

```
val res0: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[AnyVal] = List((), 2, 3)
```

Instead try `collect` which is semantically equivalent to map+filter like so

```
hashmap.collect { case (key, value) if value == 2 => key }
// val res2: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Int] = List(2, 3)
```

Comment: Can also be `.collect { case(key, 2) => key }`

Answer (score 2):

Another option you have is:

```
hashmap.filter(_._2 == 2).keys.toList
```

Or if you are also fine with `Set` you can do:

```
hashmap.filter(_._2 == 2).keySet
```